Movie about a guy who stays at a family lying about know their dead soldier son
So here's what I remember:

The movie's about a guy,who took part in some government experiments, and now he's a killing machine.
He arrives at a family's house, and says he knew their son in the military.
He helps the family's son and his sister.
The sister calls the military and finds out that he's not who he says he is.
It had awesome electronic music in it.
It's an American movie.


Related question here.

This is The Guest,

Still struggling over the loss of their eldest son, Caleb, to the war in Afghanistan, the Peterson family—Mr. and Mrs. Peterson and their children Luke and Anna—are unexpectedly visited by David Collins, a former soldier who claims to have been a friend of Caleb's [...]
Major Carver picks up Anna and informs her that her parents are dead and that David is really a former test subject for a military health program; his mental condition has been "programmed" to, if he believes his identity compromised, kill everyone who could possibly know about it.

